# Powershell Bug?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I observe a strange behaviour when calling an external script using `& cmd /c myscript.cmd`

When quite a lot of errors (let's say 200) are raised before the external script is called, the external call is not handled properly : the batch file is not executed at all.

When the number of error is not high (let's say 10), it is working normally (the external batch is called).

Is this a bug ? here is the PoC : change the value of $numberOfError to differents values (10, then 200) and see the output changing.

## PoC

```
# Creation of a temporary Batch
Set-Content foo.cmd '@echo THE BATCH SCRIPT HAS BEEN CALLED !' -Encoding ASCII
$numberOfError = 10
# $numberOfError = 200 # if high value (sometimes only 40 is enough,
# other times > 140 do the trick)
for($i=0;$i -lt $numberOfError;$i++){
    Rename-Item c:\not_existing.txt c:\blah.txt # just used to raise an Error
}
Write-Host "Before call"
# the below line won't be called if $numberOfError is >= 87 
# (might be a higher value on some other machines maybe)
& cmd /c foo.cmd

Write-Host "Still there"
```

Here is the kind of output i am getting :

## When $numberOfError = 10

```
[... Bunch of Error Messages ...]
Before call
THE BATCH SCRIPT HAS BEEN CALLED !         <------ THIS LINE CHANGE
Still there
```

## When $numberOfError = 200

```
[... Bunch of Error Messages ...]
Before call
Still there
```

Please let me know if this is a known powershell bug, i know i could handle errors but this behaviour don't seems normal to me.

P.S: Tested only with Powershell v2.0 binaries.

Comment: Easy on the bug thingie :D What are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: cant repro your "bug" even with 2000, 200 000 with -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue, errors -- tats win10(poshv5). might be some limitation of the old cmd tho ...stil I doubt :)

Comment: Unable to repro in v2.0 as well (Windows 7)

Comment: I'd bet one of those 200+ errors causes it to pass over or exit a function and it's not a bug.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen : i cannot reproduce it using powershell_ise of powergui. But with powershell the problem happens (Win7 x64 SP1 here).

Comment: @JaquelineVanek  using "-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue" seems to fix my problem. I am still curious of what kind of overflow bug that can be... Btw, depending on the number of lines in my main script, the problem happens after a different number of $numberOfError

Comment: so, how do you think? :)

Comment: slightly offtopic, aint posh even more buggy in bash on windows on cmd? :) PS looks like effin disaster, PSReadLine, mah arse...